# Why inserting into the table not working?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wonder why this piece of code is not working?

```
SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();
//string myConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=try;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
comand.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();

comand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableProduct (productID,productName) VALUES ('1','M')";

comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: any errors or exceptions?

Comment: What do you mean _is not working_? Any error messege or exception?

Comment: No errors shows. i try to debug but it doesn't show any error just not inserting into the table. sorry error is a bit ambiguous. how can i learn if there is error or exception? i tried try and catch also but doesn't get into the catch part.

Comment: Is the productID a string?

Comment: i assume the field is too small. print the query and copy to management studio, there you will see an error msg.

Comment: maybe remove the single quotes around the integer.

Comment: productid is string. i will try to create an another database and try again

Answer (score 5):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `mydatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: I wonder how many other questions on SO are answered by this... Again a feature I can't imagine ever been tested.

Comment: thnaks for the info. i will try to create an another database and try again

Answer (score 1):

Becasue you declared your `SqlCommand` as `comando` but you used it as `comand`?

Change

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
```

to

```
SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();
```

Comment: sorry i mis type it all are comand NOT comando. not working so can u erase ur answer please. i edited comando to comand.

Comment: [Commando](http://youtu.be/ymBBQN45shA)... Those were the days.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl Are you sure your connection string is correct? Are you sure you have a table called `TableProduct` and this columns are named as `productID` and `productName`? What is the types of these columns?

Comment: connection string is correct becaouse my select statement is working but not insert. thanks for the info. i will try to create an another database and try again.